# How can I compare a number to find out whether it is higher than another number?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have the following code:

```js
// CODE RELATED TO THE INPUT FIELD 
document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const guess = Number(document.querySelector('.guess').value);
  console.log(guess, typeof guess)
  const randomNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * 20);
  console.log(randomNumber);
  /* document.querySelector('.message').textContent = ' nber!' */
  if (!guess) {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'No number in the field!'
  } else if (guess === randomNumber) {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Correct!!  Good job!!'
  } else if (guess > randomNumber) {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'too high! Try again'
  } else if (guess < randomNumber) {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'too low! Try again'
  } else if (guess >= 21) {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Your number is higher than 20'
  }
})
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Guess My Number!</h1>
  <p class="between">(Between 1 and 20)</p>
  <button class="btn again">Again!</button>
  <div class="number">?</div>
</header>
<main>
  <section class="left">
    <input type="number" class="guess" />
    <button class="btn check">Check!</button>
  </section>
  <section class="right">
    <p class="message">Start guessing...</p>
    <p class="label-score"> Score: <span class="score">20</span></p>
    <p class="label-highscore">
       Highscore: <span class="highscore">0</span>
    </p>
  </section>
</main>
```

The last 'else if' of the conditional which says: else if ( guess >= 21 ) how can I edit it to make it work? I need to display: 'Your number is higher than 20. Try again!' when 'guess' is higher than 20.

Comment: You're there .. The `IF` just never "gets" there .. Make `else if (guess >= 21) {` the **first** in the line of `else ifs`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the check never reaches the condition `guess >= 21`. If you think about it, any number will either be equal to `randomNumber` (`guess === randomNumber`), bigger than `randomNumber` (`guess > randomNumber`) or smaller than it.

Instead, you should move the check before the `randomNumber` comparisons.

```js
document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const guess = Number(document.querySelector('.guess').value);
  console.log(guess, typeof guess)

  const randomNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * 20);
  console.log(randomNumber);

  if (!guess) {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'No number in the field!'
  } else if (guess >= 21) {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Your number is higher than 20'
  } else if (guess === randomNumber) {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Correct!!  Good job!!'
  } else if (guess > randomNumber) {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'too high! Try again'
  } else if (guess < randomNumber) {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'too low! Try again'
  }


})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Guess My Number!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Guess My Number!</h1>
    <p class="between">(Between 1 and 20)</p>
    <button class="btn again">Again!</button>
    <div class="number">?</div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="left">
      <input type="number" class="guess" />
      <button class="btn check">Check!</button>
    </section>
    <section class="right">
      <p class="message">Start guessing...</p>
      <p class="label-score"> Score: <span class="score">20</span></p>
      <p class="label-highscore">
         Highscore: <span class="highscore">0</span>
      </p>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work properly because the `guess > randomNumber` condition is defined first. You need to define it somehow differently. For example:

```
if (!guess) {
  document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'No number in the field!'
} else if (guess === randomNumber) {
  document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Correct!!  Good job!!'
} else if (guess < randomNumber) { 
  document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'too low! Try again' 
} else if ( guess >= 21 && guess < 1000) {
  document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Your number is higher than 20' 
} else if (guess > randomNumber && guess > 999) {
   document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'too high! Try again'
}
```

**If you don't define additional conditions `&& guess < 1000` and `&& guess > 999`, then you will never see the answer: 'too high! Try again'.**

Good luck!